# Visual Studio Online - Build Drop Only Contains Log Files

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I was trying out the new Visual Studio 2013 online with Express edition for web.
I created a sample project and a build definition for it, selected "Hosted Build Controller" and with option to "copy build output to the server".

I then queued a build and it succeeded on Visual Studio Online. However, when I click on "Drownload drop as zip" it gives me a zip file with just the log files.

Is there a way to download published website files or am I asking for too much with the free license?

Comment: What do you see in the build logs?

Comment: Did the build actually succeed?

Comment: Yes, the build succeeded. The only warning that I see is like "Copy binaries to drop00:00:00
TF270003: Failed to copy. Ensure the source directory C:\a\bin exists and that you have the appropriate permissions".

Comment: Did you ensure that the directory exists and that you have appropriate permissions?

Comment: @AndrewClear the build path is on the TFS build server which is somwewhere on Windows cloud. How can I check for permission?

Comment: Good point... I should have read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may lie in your build output settings. If you hadn't noticed yet, there are few more "Staging location" options in TFS 2013 under the Build Defaults tab in your Build Definition.

[image: New staging locations]

Assuming you're sticking with the "Hosted Build Controller", your best bet is to select, "Copy build output to the following Source Control folder" option.

The alternative is to create your own, on-premises build controller and point it at your VisualStudio.com URL. Then you could choose traditional UNC path. More on that scaling out here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd793166.aspx

Also: when choosing to copy build output to a source control folder, you may want to 'cloak' that path in your Workspace settings to prevent downloading *all* your build output locally when you perform a get-latest. That is, unless you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. I changed the location of my solution and I needed to update the build process file:

1. In the team explorer, select builds.
2. Under all build definitions, select your build. Right click > edit build definition.
3. Click process on the left.
4. Under build > look at #2. Confirm that your solution location is correct.